# Which is correct definition of "Abstraction in Java."

Tags: java

I am having trouble in understanding the meaning of "Abstraction in Java". I googled, and studied books, in those I got two types of definitions.

1. Choosing necessary properties and hiding unwanted details is Abstraction.
2. Abstraction is the concept of simplifying one idea to a more general, overhead idea.

I feel above two definitions don't mean same, and are entirely different.

So which is correct one?

Comment: There is no special meaning of abstractions in Java rather than in OOP

Comment: The first definition sounds to me more like encapsulation than abstraction.

Comment: @Vulcan Encapsulation definitely is a tool to achieve abstraction.

Comment: search google without quates

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik True, but I wouldn't consider them to be synonymous.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443177/abstraction-and-abstract-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I think both your statement have same meaning if you think deeply.

Hiding necessary properties and hiding unwanted details leads you to more general, overhead idea.

suppose Animal is a abstract class we hide the nature of animal and their food habits in abstract class and when we talk about Tiger we introduce all the revelant details,

Comment: But they clearly tell as "Hiding Unwanted Details", this could be wrong, because, while defining common idea,concept, we dont have specific properties only, then how we are doing hiding there..?

Still in confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Abstraction is hiding of data.
Means IF you have a class A which contain 2 variables suppose int id,String name 
in which if you want to keep that data protected in your class you will keep
Id as private variable so your variable is not directly accessible outside class.

This way you can approach to handle abstraction in class.